# Simple limit problem with $a^x$.

Tags: limits

Any idea of calculating the limit of $f(x)=2^x/3^{x^2}$ when $x$ approaches infinate? I looked up the function in geogebra and the limit is zero. Not sure how to prove it though... I guess using the L' Hospital (not sure if spelled correctly) rule.

Comment: Hint: take the logarithm.

Comment: Did you try L'hopital's rule.That should work.

Comment: Don't do l'Hopital, it'll be gross

Comment: Btw, both of the spellings l'Hopital and l'Hospital are commonly found in textbooks. I prefer l'Hopital, since students are less likely to pronounce it "La Hospital".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x>1$, $x^{2}>x$, so $$0<\frac{2^{x}}{3^{x^{2}}}<\frac{2^{x}}{3^{x}} \to 0$$
So the sequence has to tend to $0$.

Comment: So you are using the theorem:

z<x<y  If limz=k and limy=k then limx=k Right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $2^x = e^{\ln(2)x}$ and $3^{x^2} = e^{\ln(3)x^2}$. Thus $$\frac{2^{x}}{3^{x^2}} = e^{-\ln(3)x^2 + \ln(2) x}.$$

Thus as $x\to \infty$ we have $-\ln(3)x^2+\ln(2)x \to -\infty$ (since $\ln(3) > 0$) so we conclude $$\frac{2^x}{3^{x^2}} =  e^{-\ln(3)x^2 + \ln(2) x}\to 0$$ as $x\to \infty$. (Remember $e^{x} \to 0$ as $x\to -\infty$.)

Comment: When When x→+∞ then −ln(3)x2→−∞ and ln(2)x→+∞ which leads in an uknown form of ( -∞ +∞) ...

Comment: Don't think of a polynomial as its individual terms. The only term that matters for large $x$ is the leading one. Thus $x^3 - x^2 \to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$ and $-x^2+x \to -\infty$ as $x\to\infty$. @user253724

Comment: In this specific case we can actually graph $f(x) = -\ln(3)x^2 + \ln(2) x = x(\ln(2) - \ln(3)x)$. This is a parabola facing downwards, with zeros $x=0$ and $x = \ln(2)/\ln(3)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: When $x\to+\infty$, note $$\frac{2^x}{3^{x^2} } = \left(\frac{2}{3^x}\right)^x.$$
When $x\to -\infty$, note $$ \frac{2^x}{3^{x^2} } = 2^x 3^{- x^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{2^x}{3^{x^2}}$$
For $x\geq 1$, we have
$$2\leq 2^x\leq 2^{x^2}$$
$$\frac{2}{3^{x^2}}\leq\frac{2^x}{3^{x^2}} \leq \frac{2^{x^2}}{3^{x^2}}$$
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{2}{3^{x^2}}\leq\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^x}{3^{x^2}} \leq \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^{x^2}}{3^{x^2}}$$
$$0\leq\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^x}{3^{x^2}} \leq 0$$
Therefore 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{2^x}{3^{x^2}}=0$$